# How to decorate a parent property's getter or setter?

Tags: python, properties, decorator

I have defined a property `area` and its getter in a parent class `Shape`. In a child class `Square` I would like to expand the getter functionality of `area`. I wrote something which doesn't work:

#### version 1

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self):
        self._area = None

    @property
    def area(self):
        print('hello parent')
        return self._area
    
    # setter of `area` could be also defined here; hence in the child
    # I would like to keep `area`, only decorating its getter.

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Square, self).__init__()

        area = Shape.area.getter(self.dosomething())

    def dosomething(self):
        def new_func():
            print('hello child')
            Shape.area.fget(self)
        return new_func

sq = Square()
```

When I run the code, I don't get the 'hello child':

```
>>> sq.area
hello parent
```

There are some obvious problems with my code above. For example, in `Square` I should have

```
self.area = Shape.area.getter(self.dosomething())
```

rather than no `self`. Then I would need to define the `setter` of `area` in parent...

#### version 2

After some fiddling, I came up with the following code,

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self):
        self._area = None

    @property
    def area(self):
        print('hello parent')
        return self._area


class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Square, self).__init__()

    @Shape.area.getter
    def area(self):
        print('hello child')
        Shape.area.fget(self)


sq = Square()
```

This time, it seems to do what I want:

```
>>> sq.area
hello child
hello parent
```

However, my ide tells me the line `def area(self):` in `Square` "overrides method in Shape".
Furthermore, IDE also says in `Shape.area.fget(self)`, `self` is an unexpected argument. Even though the code runs without error.

It feels like version 2 is a hack. Why is my ide complaining? I thought in version 2 I did not define a brand-new `area`, just decorating the inherited `area`'s `fget`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the getter of the child class' `area` property make use of the parent's `area` property and expand on its value, in which case the child's getter function should call `super()` to access the parent's property. As for making the child's setter make use of the parent's setter you would have to access the parent's setter via the `fset` attribute of the parent class' property:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self):
        self._area = 'hello parent'

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self._area

    @area.setter
    def area(self, value):
        self._area = value

class Square(Shape):
    @property
    def area(self):
        return super().area + ' and child'

    @area.setter
    def area(self, value):
        Shape.area.fset(self, 'very ' + value)

sq = Square()
print(sq.area)
sq.area = 'new parent'
print(sq.area)
```

This outputs:

```
hello parent and child
very new parent and child
```

Alternatively, you can define new getter and setter methods in the child class and call `property` on them:

```
class Square(Shape):
    def area_getter(self):
        return super().area + ' and child'

    def area_setter(self, value):
        Shape.area.fset(self, 'very ' + value)

    area = property(area_getter, area_setter)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This works; but I would like to retain the `area` defined in the parent, for example, its `setter` could have been defined in its parent. How do I do that then?

Comment: I see. For the setter `super()` wouldn't work in an assignment so you'd have to call the parent's setter method directly. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again. So did I understand it correctly that there is no way of just "decorating" parent's property. The only way is to _override_ `area`, and somehow 'port' parent's `area`'s fget and fset into the new one in child.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by decorating parent's property. I've updated my answer with what I think you might mean.

Comment: I mean, in you answer, in `Square`, there are these two lines: `@property\\def area(self):` which defined a brand-new `area` property, right? I updated my question with a version 2 of the code, maybe that explains my intended behavior for the code better.

Comment: If that's what you mean then yes, you do have to define a new `area` property for the child class since you want the child's `area` to behave differently from the parent's. The child's `area` property can make use of the parent's internally, but since it behaves differently you simply have to define it explicitly.

Comment: In version 2 of my code, did I also defined a new `area` in the child?

Comment: Yes you did, with `def area(self):` in the child class.

Comment: I am still quite confused (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling I arrive at this solution:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self):
        self._area = None

    @property
    def area(self):
        print('hello parent')
        return self._area

    @area.setter
    def area(self, val):
        print('parent setter')
        self._area = val


class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Square, self).__init__()

    @Shape.area.getter
    def area(self):
        print('hello child')
        return super().area

    @area.setter
    def area(self, val):
        print('setter in child')
        Shape.area.fset(self, val)  # IDE complains that val is unexpected. Why?


sq = Square()
```

It does what I wanted, with a remaining issue: ide complaines that `val` is unexpected in the setter part in `Square` (noted in the code). This runs without problems though. Getting rid of `self` in that line raises error when running the code. I don't understand this. Feels like this is a hack.

I think the conclusion I arrive is that you are not supposed to expand on parent class's properties.